# turnsLeft векторы на Java

Tags: java, c#

Код на Java, Q - Stack точек. Непонятно (код не мой, препод дал), что такое turnsLeft. Вроде какой-то поворот одного вектора относительно другого, но непонятно. Что делает этот метод?

```
    Point p2 = Q.Pop();
    Point p1 = Q.Pop();
    Point p0 = Q.Pop();
    Vector p0p1 = new Vector(p1.X - p0.X, p1.Y - p0.Y);
    Vector p1p2 = new Vector(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y);
    if (p0p1.turnsLeft(p1p2))
    {
        Q.Push(p0);
        Q.Push(p1);
        Q.Push(p2);
    }
```

(26.11)Есть ли аналог на C#?

Comment: Код берет из стека 3 2-D точки и проверяет, не является ли вектор `p0p1` поворотом вектора `p1p2`. Если так, то точки пушатся в стек в несколько другом порядке.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець В смысле "являться поворотом"? То есть имеют ли вектора общую точку?

Comment: Мы не видим что проверяет метод turnsLeft(). Приходится только догадываться по его названию...

Answer (score 0):

Нарисуйте на бумаге три точки и проведите отрезки от первой ко второй и от второй к третьей. Получилась эдакая дорожка - полилиния.

Функция `turnsLeft()` проверяет (скорее всего, с использованием знака векторного произведения), в какую сторону поворачивает полилиния в средней точке при движении от первой к последней. Если влево, то две последних точки меняются местами.

Comment: Спасибо!! 
А есть ли что-то похожее/аналог на C#?

Comment: Оно на шарпе будет почти точно так же выглядеть

Comment: У меня красным подчеркивает красным(( Какой using System нужен? @MBo

Comment: эту функцию нужно написать